# SharePoint 2013 Security updates installed accidentally

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, cumulative-update, patching

During our monthly patching, our patch engineer installed SharePoint security updates accidentally on SharePoint which were part of SharePoint 2013 Jan 2019 CU. Its been a week since it is been installed and it is on Prod. Since Jan 19 CU is very latest and hence we dont want to take a risk of installing them on Prod straight away.

What could be the best remediation plan here? (Is it a good idea to install the same security updates on staging and test application, by doing so we might spoil staging farm intentionally.) or wait for some months and go for a complete CU install.

Comment: which security updates they installed? if you are on June 2019 CU thats mean you may already have those installed.

Comment: We are currently on Nov 17 CU, the security updates that got installed belong to Jan 19 CU.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont think you can uninstall it. In this situation, i would complete the patching process. Run the config wizard on all server and complete the patch.

I would also do the same on the lower environment as well because your prod is now (may be) higher build number.

Comment: But Jan 19 CU is very latest, is ok to patch it after 2 months on Prod?

Comment: you can wait for the CU but as you already installed the Security fix in Prod, i would match the same in lower farm.